# Android Image Captured Being Saved in Custom Folder and Gallery Folder

Tags: android

I am currently capturing and saving an image in a specific folder successfully and having a specific name that i choose. the problem is that the image is also being saved in the gallery having a different name. how can i delete the image in the gallery.

this is how i am capturing the image.

```
           Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);    
                File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), this.getResources().getString(R.string.attachments_folder));
File image = new File(imagesFolder, "IM_" + timeStamp + ".jpeg");
                Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image); intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
```

Comment: Create a file named `.nomedia` inside this directory, it will say android not to scan this directory when looking for images. The images that has already been scanned will not disappear from the gallery, but the one added after the creation of this `.nomedia` should not be shown by the Gallery.

Comment: okay i will try that now thanks